# Triplet of integers such that expression is prime for every prime number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, quadratics

Using only elementary methods known to a middle schooler taking his first algebra course, is there a triplet of integers $(a, b, c)$ such that, for every prime number $p$, $(5a + 4)p^2 + (5b + 3)p + 2c$ is a prime number?

I know that if an even integer is a prime number, then it is $2$.

Comment: without knowing anything about the subject - is the betting window open?

Comment: On the one hand, granted that $p=2$ is included, then your triplet must satisfy $$10a+5b+c=-10\,,$$ which implies that $b,c$ are both of the same parity.....on the other hand, this question is (a restriction to prime number arguments of) the problem of the infinitude of primes in quadratic progressions, which here requires that the discriminant $$(5b+3)^2-8c(5b+4)$$ is not a square number.

Comment: I think we can disprove this in a similar way than proving that there is no non-constant polynomial $f(n)$ with integer coefficients that is prime for every integer $n$. I guess someone will do this soon. Unfortunately, I have no concrete idea for the disproof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such $a,b,c$ exist.

Let $f(x)=(5a+4)x^2+(5b+3)x+2c$. Let $f(3)=q$. Then $f(kq+3)$ is a multiple of $q$ for all $k$. And by Dirichlet's Theorem $kq+3$ is prime for infinitely many $k$.

Now it's not possible to prove Dirichlet's Theorem by middle school methods, but at least the statement of Dirichlet's Theorem is quite simple. It says that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there are infinitely many $n$ such that $an+b$ is prime.